# while loop failing running command

Tags: bash, function, while-loop

I picked up this script from here which I modified into a function. But the function will timeout if the executing task takes too long. Is there anway to prevent this? It works great for tasks under minute or so, but with a long task compiling and building a file, it times out, which causes the main script to throw a syntax error exception. Is their a way to prevent this or another method for longer executions?

```
 srun() {
     while true;do echo -n .;sleep 1;done &
        eval "$1"
     kill $!; trap 'kill $!' SIGTERM
 }
```

Comment: There is no reason why this would time out. Is the command you're executing (`$1`) itself timing out?

Comment: No, i had to remove the function and just screen into a new session, which runs fine, and and then need user input to exit the screen (or add exit) but what is running is a whole bunch of nonsense which won't make sense to the user which is why I was trying to mask it.

Can part of the variable script contain quoting that would break it? Should I omit quoting `$1`? I believe I had issues when I did that before.

Comment: all the command is as well is a git push and java invocation. No quotes in the code being ran (unless output from the commands is causing it) there is a variable `${version}` in the command, though. Issue I'm having using screen in general, is when the screen terminates `[screen is terminating]`, it clears the parent terminal window of all previous script prompting and messages.